# Reading fixed width text file with different length

Tags: java

I have a text file that is in fixed width format, except each column has a different length.  I have about 100 columns in all.

For example, the first few columns of text have the following width:

30
4
188

Let's assume I read in the first row from the file.  How do I seperate/map the text into 100 different size columns?

Comment: your question is very vague.

Comment: i changed the question to a single one, does that make it more clear?

Comment: do you have a more concrete example ?

Comment: If the data in a row has a separator like `' '` or `;` or something else, use `String#split`. You should show what you have tried so far. If you've done something and it doesn't work properly please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get help from community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just dealt with this at work within the last few weeks.  The way we went about solving the problem was to create an enum class with corresponding "indexes" to represent the start and end positions of the fields that needed to be extracted.  This enum is loaded into a map of FIELD_NAME --> RANGE (i.e. 0:8) upon instantiation of the class that parses the message.

High-level, upon receipt of a message on the queue:

- convert TextMessage to string
- read line
- for each field, get the corresponding range from the map
- split the range on ":" to get the indexes
- extract the values from the String using substring(index1,index2)
- perform transformations (string to date, string to numbers, etc)
- persist to database

Comment: Listing 10 in the following article takes a similar approach to the way in which we dealt with the enum: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-enum-class-in-java/26900